# Remove a div class with condition

Tags: plugins, php, themes

Hi all I am newbie in wordpress

I have a problem in remove or override an action/function in my parent theme
my goal is show a display-job-card simply just a currency symbol with condition
in my child theme.

below are code in my parent theme:

```
<div class="flex-master card-job-price text-right text-vertical-center">

                <?php if ( get_option( 'wpjobster_packages_enabled' ) == 'yes' && get_post_meta( $pid, 'job_packages', true ) == 'yes' && $package_price_vals ) { ?>

                    <span class="small-job"><?php _e( 'Starting at', 'wpjobster' ); ?></span>
                    <span class="display-price-card"><?php echo wpjobster_get_show_price( min( $package_price_vals ) ); ?></span>

                <?php } elseif ( get_post_meta( $pid, 'price_type', true ) ) { ?>

                    <span class="small-job"><?php echo sprintf( __( '%s Rate', 'wpjobster' ), wpjobster_translate_string( get_post_meta( $pid, 'price_type', true ) ) ); ?></span>
                    <span class="display-price-card"><?php echo wpjobster_get_show_price( get_post_meta( $pid, 'price', true ), 2, true ); ?></span>

                <?php } else { echo wpjobster_get_show_price( get_post_meta( $pid, 'price', true ), 2, true ); } ?>

            </div>
```

I have three types of 'price_type' custom/package and fixed.
I would like to show "display-price-card" under price_type (package and fixed) only.
I am not asking for the exact code. I am hoping someone who could give me some guidelines,
logic.

I've done a lot of research however, i can't find any apply_filter nor do_action in here.
I am not sure how i can get into this class and how to o it right...

Please help and thanks all of you!

Comment: Also have no idea how to locate action hooks/function of class="small-job and class="display-price-card"

Comment: If hooks (filters and actions) are not available, then you could try overriding the entire template via a child theme. If it's not a template, but custom code in a non-pluggable function (a function not wrapped in `if ( ! function_exists( 'some_func' ) )`, then I guess you'd have to edit the original file.

Comment: 3rd-party theme support is off-topic though on this site. So you should try contacting the theme authors and ask for their guidance in overriding the hook/code, template, etc.

Comment: thank you so much for your advice guess i would have to do some more research...